# setOnClickListener not working in fragment in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment

I am try to call my imageid in fragment class but its show error and also show error in setOnClickListener.
I am try every think please if you have any answer then please share it.

//This is a code

```
class Home : Fragment() {
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val view: View = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)

    view.Notification.setOnClickListener { view ->   //Notification is a id of imageView
        Log.d("btnSetup", "Selected")
    }

    return view
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

To get a view from an id you need to call `findViewById`. In your case:

```
view.findViewById<View>(R.id.Notification).setOnClickListener { view ->
    Log.d("btnSetup", "Selected")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to do in `onViewCreated` as follow:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.Notification).setOnClickListener { view -> 
        Log.d("btnSetup", "Selected")
    }
}
```